# is Java JRE included with SE install

Tags: java

If I have Java SE installed, does this include JRE?

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but Java 1.6 reached End Of Life in December 2015.  Why do you still want to use it?

Comment: When you installing JDK intall ask you to install public JRE as well. You able to skip it. In any case you have java.exe in your JDK

Comment: JRE is the abbreviation for "Java Runtime Environment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed jdk 1.6 it should have contained the jre of course. I don't know what your issue is but have you added your jdk directory to your path?

Answer (score 2):

As JRE is short for Java Runtime Environment, the answer is yes.

**Java**(TM) SE **Runtime Environment** (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)